# Formatting stripped sending from Outlook 2016 and received on Outlook 2013

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office-2013, microsoft-office-2016

My company is in the process of upgrading to Office 2016. We have users who are on Office 2013 and are receiving formatted e-mails with the formatting stripped out. To the Office 2016 sender - everything looks fine. To the Office 2013 recipient -  the formatting is all stripped out. It may be happening more frequently, but the most noticeable instances of it happening is when the Office 2016 sender includes a table embedded in the e-mail. The Office 2013 recipient gets the e-mail and the table is gone and everything is tabbed weird, colors removed, etc.

Comment: We've since discovered that this issue only appears to happen on *newly sent* meeting invites. Meeting invites which are just updated by an Office 2016 user can be received by the Office 2013 user with the table intact. But if the Office 2016 user sends a meeting invite to the Office 2013 user with a table, it's stripped out.

Comment: Update your question then delete your comment.